# CodeIgniter Register with Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to register with Facebook, and I am using [this](https://github.com/falexandrou/Codeigniter-Social-Register) plugin. It redirects me to facebook login page but when I login to facebook, it doesn't return me back to my website.

**Controller**

```
class UserController extends CI_Controller { 
    public function fbSignup() {
    $this->load->library('fb');
    if (!$this->fb->is_connected()) {

        redirect($this->fb->login_url(current_url()));
    }

    $fb_user = $this->fb->client->api('/me');
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($fb_user); exit;
    if (empty($fb_user)) {
        $error = "FACEBOOK LOGIN FAILED - USER US EMPTY. FILE: " . __FILE__ . " LINE: " . __LINE__;
        $this->session->set_flashdata('register_error', $error);
    } else {
        $this->user->set_facebook_id($fb_user['id']);
        $user = $this->user->get_by_facebook();
        if (!empty($user) && !empty($user->id) && is_numeric($user->id)) {
            //TODO: Make things a bit more secure here
            //Login & Redirect home
            $this->_login($user->id, 'facebook');
            $this->load->view('users/redirect_home');
            return;
        }
    }
}

}
```

All the app sercrets and API keys are set

Answer (score 0):

you don`t need to use any CodeIgniter plugin you can do that simply using Javascript library, using JS library there is two advantages --

01) you can use this script any framework like CodeIgniter, CakePHP, Laravel etc. i mean when you will start work on new framework then you don`t need to waste your time simply use this script.

02) using JS you can open login form of facecbook on your website in popup window it will not redirect to facebook.com page.

Script --

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '717505658366417', // Set YOUR APP ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

  };

    function Login()
    {

        FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) 
           {
                getUserInfo();
            } else 
            {
             console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
         },{scope: 'email,user_photos,user_videos'});

    }

  function getUserInfo() {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      var str="<b>Name</b> : "+response.name+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Link: </b>"+response.link+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Gender:</b> "+response.gender+"<br>";
          str +="<b>id: </b>"+response.id+"<br>";
          str +="<b>Email:</b> "+response.email+"<br>";
          str +="<input type='button' value='Get Photo' onclick='getPhoto();'/>";
          str +="<input type='button' value='Logout' onclick='Logout();'/>";
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=str;

    });
    }
    function getPhoto()
    {
      FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {

          var str="<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
          document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+=str;

    });

    }
    function Logout()
    {
        FB.logout(function(){document.location.reload();});
    }

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

</script>
<div align="center">
<h2>Facebook OAuth Javascript Demo</h2>

<div id="message">
Logs:<br/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not returning any thing, it logs in but I can't see any thing in return